# Custom list data doesn’t appear consistent in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, custom-lists

I have a list that seems to be acting oddly.

The list has 5 custom columns. 2 columns are text fields, the others are lookup fields.

When I view the list I see data in all 5 columns. When I edit a pre-existing item I see data only in the Title field.

When I add a new item I can add data to all columns. However, once I am back viewing the list view I only see the Title field data for this new item (pre-existing items still show as mentioned above). When I edit this new item I then can see all the data I originally entered.

Does anyone have any idea of what might be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone created additional columns that had the same display name.  Those columns were being shown in the View.

Removed the additional columns, modified the view and all is well.

Sometimes it is the simple things.